# Single Page Application & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, singlepage

Are these two a good fit for each other? Is there any reference/screencast/book explaining howcome I:

- build a primitive SPA on top of ASP.NET MVC 3/4 (any other language/framework is ok provided that next two requirements are adhered;
- Use `History API` with `History.js` fallback;
- Configure routes.

Comment: have you even tried to google? there are some very good complete tutorial on this, including videos from pluralsight http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa

Comment: @rouen Share your thought as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some very good complete tutorial on this, including videos from pluralsight

http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here as well:

http://tarkus.me/post/32121691785/angularjs-with-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 1):

At the end I choose the following stack to work with:

- `ASP.NET MVC 3/4`;
- `require.js`;
- `backbone.js`;
- `Twitter Bootstrap / Zurb Foundation 3`